# Mal formatação do campo ao exportar o relatório do Crystar report para PDF

Tags: crystal-reports

Fiz um mapa usando o crystal reports e ao exporta-lo para PDF o texto da coluna descrição é mal formatado incluindo mais espaços, conforme pode se ver nas imagens seguintes.

[image: Antes de exportar para o PDF]
Antes de exportar para PDF.

[image: Depois de exportar]

Depois de exportar para PDF.

Alguém sabe como ultrapassamos esse desafio? Obrigado!

Comment: Ao meu ver esta questão tem haver com o Crystal report e as configurações da máquina do utilizador. Apenas marquei a tag Primavera para ver se alguém que usa o primavera já terá enfrentado o mesmo desafio. A tag Crystal Reports está inclusa.

Comment: Qual a versão do Crystal?

Comment: Vê este link de suport do crystal. Aparentemente é um bug conhecido que existe na versão 2008, que é o motor da V10. https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1546135

Comment: A versão do crystal é 10

Comment: Verifique a minha resposta aplique a solução ao registry e reinicie a máquina e por favor retire o tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Crystal em alguns casos reduz o tamanho da fonte ao exportar para PDF com o objectivo de evitar omissões no texto.

Pode ser resolvido com a adição de um chave no Registry.

Já tive sucesso com a solução apresentada neste artigo: [Font size is reduced after exporting a custom Crystal Report to PDF](http://www.kb.blackbaud.co.uk/articles/Article/54699)

E também nesta pergunta do SOen: [Font size is decreased when exporting Crystal Report to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212290/font-size-is-decreased-when-exporting-crystal-report-to-pdf)